# htaccess - outputting semi-colon's & spaces in the querystring

Tags: .htaccess

I'm struggling with .htaccess
The site has the URL

```
http:/www.example.com/section-1/product640/page.html
```

Which needs to be redirected to:

```
http:/www.example.com/section/c/27?dynNav=Type::query%20string;
```

Note the space and semicolon in the querystring.

My htaccess rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^section-1/product640/([^/]+)$ /section/c/27?dynNav=Type::query%20string; [L,R=301,NC]
```

But this returns:

```
http://www.example.com/section/c/27?dynNav=Type::query0string%3b
```

I believe the zero in "query0string" is because it's taking the %2 as a variable, which doesn't exist. So the question is, how do I encode the space?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing '%20' with '\ ' like this should solve your problem:

```
RewriteRule ^section-1/product640/([^/]+)$ /section/c/27?dynNav=Type::query\ string; [L,R=302,NC]
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it doesn't appear to work - the output is still the same.

Comment: you had 301 code in the response so your browser might be using the previous response from the server. Have you tried in 'incognito mode'?